# PowerBI Server - View reports in mobile format

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

Is it possible to view [PowerBI Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/get-started) deployed reports in the [mobile format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-create-phone-report) using a browser, without using the [PowerBI Mobile application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/mobile-app-ssrs-kpis-mobile-on-premises-reports)?

By default, if you open a report on a mobile browser, it opens a scaled down version of the full-size view.

Perhaps there is a url parameter that requests the mobile version of the report, similar to [`?rs:embed=true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed) appended to the end of the report url? (`?rs:mobile=true` has no effect)

Could not find anything on this.

**Edit** - currently, as a workaround considering creating versions of desktop reports with small resolution set under "Page Size" in "Format" tab, but this would be far from ideal (Reports rendered as desktop reports, Filters and tabs panes visible, inconvenient maintenance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the feature request on the PowerBI community site - No is the short answer to you r question.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31852918-make-phone-layout-available-in-web-browser